# Dynamixel problem : No motors found

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I just got a new computer on which I installed ros groovy.

I am trying to use Dynamixel motors but I have an error. This error doesn't appear each time I launch the script so it's why I don't understand what's happening.

Below is the error :

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1371628756.187555] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 1 through 25...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1371628756.271966] pan_tilt_port controller_spawner: waiting for controller_manager dxl_manager to startup in global namespace...
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1371628758.257885] pan_tilt_port: No motors found.
================================================================================
REQUIRED process [dynamixel_manager-2] has died!
```

Here is my launch file :

```
<launch>
    <node name="dynamixel_manager" pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_manager.py" required="true" output="screen">
        <rosparam>
            namespace: dxl_manager
            serial_ports:
                pan_tilt_port:
                    port_name: "/dev/Motors"
                    baud_rate: 1000000
                    min_motor_id: 1
                    max_motor_id: 25
                    update_rate: 20
        </rosparam>
    </node>

    <!-- Start tilt joint controller -->
    <rosparam file="$(find emox_dynamixel)/tilt.yaml" command="load"/>

    <node name="tilt_controller_spawner" pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_spawner.py"
          args="--manager=dxl_manager
        --port=pan_tilt_port
        base_tilt_controller
        pico_tilt_controller
        pan_controller
        tilt_controller"
          output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

The strange thing is that I can launch the script several times and got the error, and the second after (without changing anything) I launch it again and it works perfectly well. So the motors are connected and recognized by the computer.

Does someone have an idea about why I have this problem ?
Thanks,

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65478/dynamixel-problem-:-no-motors-found/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same Problem. I've solved it by downloading the Dynamixel RoboPlus software http://www.robotis.com/xe/download_en. It provides the Dynamixel Wizard which will search for any motor attached. You can then change all of its settings.

In my case the baud rate was way off, like Teja Krishna already guessed.

---

Originally posted by [AlexKolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20130/alexkolb/) with karma: 30 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) on 2015-04-01**:
I had this problem with my MX-64AR, and I even roboPlus doesn't help. I use usb2dynamixel and a power box to support..... it makes me crazy now....

**Comment by [AlexKolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20130/alexkolb/) on 2015-04-01**:
Hi just to make sure: Have you checked if the usb2dynamixel adaper ist set to the right protocol? And if it is, is one of the red led's flashing when you search for motors?

**Comment by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) on 2015-04-01**:
Hi, Alex, I am sure the adaptor is set to RS485 (in the middle position), and red led is flashing.